# Ошибка при использовании find_element_by_name Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

начал учить Selenium и решил написать простенькую прогу которая будет жать на чекбокс.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
useragent = UserAgent()
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={useragent.random}")

service = Service("C:\\Users\\Anon\\PycharmProjects\\Selenium test\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://mega.nz/register"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(1)

    checkbox2 = driver.find_element_by_name("register-check2")

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

получаю следующую ошибку: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name',
а Pycharm выдает такую подсказку: Unresolved attribute reference 'find_element_by_name' for class 'WebDriver'

Как решить данную проблему не знаю, так что за любой ответ буду благодарен!

Ps версия Selenium - 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понизь версию силениума, чтобы данный синтаксис работал (ты используешь синтаксис силениума версии 3):

```
pip3 install 'selenium<4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, функция *find_element_by_name* "was depricated" и на данный момент отсутствует в файле webdriver.py библиотеки selenium==4.4.0.
Исходя из официальной документации([python-selenium документация](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)) вам необходимо использовать:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
checkbox2 = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "register-check2")
```